# VBA finding the last instance of a phrase before a different key phrase?

Tags: html, vba, search, excel

I have a large string that comes from an HTML source code (approximately 1,000,000 characters long). I'm using msinet.ocx to view the text from appropriate websites. I've written a small segment of code in order to find a key phrase ("pkid=") that occurs right before a different key phrase ("Component Accessory Matrix"), but it's not working properly. Here's what I have right now:

```
workbench = Cells(columnNumber, 1).Value
myURL = "http://beams.us.yazaki.com/Beams/ViewDetails.aspx?topic=document&pkid=" _
& workbench
Dim inet1 As Inet
Dim mypage As String

Set inet1 = New Inet
With inet1
    .Protocol = icHTTP
    .URL = myURL
    mypage = .OpenURL(.URL, icString)
End With

CAMnum = InStr(mypage, "Component Accessory Matrix")
intStart = InStrRev(mypage, "pkid=", CAMnum) + 5
newnum = Mid(mypage, intStart, 6)
Cells(columnNumber, 2).Value = newnum
```

The problem seems to be with `mypage = .OpenURL(.URL, icString)`; when I run `len(mypage)`, it returns a value of approximately 100,000, when it should be returning a value of about a million. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `InStr` and `InStrRev`, find your string, and look backwards. Once you have that position, look from there forwards until we find the quote character. Finally, use those positions to get the string

```
pos1 = InStrRev(YourXMLString, "pkid=", InStr(YourXMLString, "Component Accessory Matrix")) + 5 ' length of "pkid="
pos2 = InStr(pos1, YourXMLString, Chr(34)) ' Chr(34)="
FoundString = Mid$(YourXMLString, pos1, pos2 - pos1)
```

Note that if *"Component Accessory Matrix"* is missing, or doesn't have *"pkid="* before it, or the quote is not the delimiter, or more text comes between *pkid=* and the quote mark, the code will fail and/or produce nonsense results.

Answer (score 1):

Use the HTML DOM.

- Load the text into a HTML Document:

  ```
  Dim html As Object ' MSHTML.HTMLDocument  
  Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")  
  html.body.innerHTML = "your HTML code here"
  ```
- Use [getElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname.aspx) to grab the collection of `td` elements:

  ```
  Dim tdElements As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection  
  Set tdElements = html.getElementsByTagName("td")
  ```
- Loop through them until you find the one whose inner text is "Component Accessory Matrix", then grab the inner text of the previous `td` element.

  ```
  Dim tdElement As Object ' MSHTML.IHTMLElement  
  Dim i As Long  
  Dim textToParse As String  
  For i = 1 to tdElements.Count  
    If tdElements.Item(i).innerText = "Component Accessory Matrix" Then  
      ' get previous <td>  
      Set tdElement = tdElements.Item(i - 1)  
      textToParse = tdElement.innerText  
      Exit For  
    End If  
  Next i
  ```
- Parse the string using traditional methods

I would split the resulting string by `=` and take the second element, then split that string by `"` and take the first element. That leaves you with `300451`.

[Here's a further example if you need it](http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/an-exploration-of-ie-browser-methods-part-iii/).

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I do run into a problem with your solution: the code that I have is really long, and it's to be downloaded from a website. Also, I have 147 of these to complete, so I  have to write a macro for downloading the HTML from the specific website. Here's what I have so far:

Comment: `workbench = Cells(columnNumber, 1).Value
    myURL = "http://beams.us.yazaki.com/Beams/ViewDetails.aspx?topic=document&pkid=" _
    & workbench
    Dim inet1 As Inet
    Dim mypage As String
    
    Set inet1 = New Inet
    With inet1
        .Protocol = icHTTP
        .URL = myURL
        mypage = .OpenURL(.URL, icString)
    End With
    
    CAMnum = InStr(mypage, "Component Accessory Matrix")
    intStart = InStrRev(mypage, "pkid=", CAMnum) + 5
    newnum = Mid(mypage, intStart, 6)
    Cells(columnNumber, 2).Value = newnum`

Comment: Oh, sorry, it didn't format the code properly. If you need the formatted code, I could message it to you. But anyway, the problem I'm having is that the .OpenURL method isn't fully saving the entire HTML document. It's about 3,000,000 characters, but it's only saving about 100,000 of them. Do you know why this would happen?

Comment: @user1515191 Please update your question instead of leaving comments.