# Is there a limitation to the string length with VBA?

Tags: string, vba, excel

I have a large string that comes from an HTML source code (approximately 1,000,000 characters long). I'm using msinet.ocx to view the text from appropriate websites. I've written a small segment of code in order to find a key phrase ("pkid=") that occurs right before a different key phrase ("Component Accessory Matrix"), but it's not working properly. Here's what I have right now:

```
workbench = Cells(columnNumber, 1).Value
myURL = "http://beams.us.yazaki.com/Beams/ViewDetails.aspx?topic=document&pkid=" _
& workbench
Dim inet1 As Inet
Dim mypage As String

Set inet1 = New Inet
With inet1
    .Protocol = icHTTP
    .URL = myURL
    mypage = .OpenURL(.URL, icString)
End With

CAMnum = InStr(mypage, "Component Accessory Matrix")
intStart = InStrRev(mypage, "pkid=", CAMnum) + 5
newnum = Mid(mypage, intStart, 6)
Cells(columnNumber, 2).Value = newnum
```

The problem seems to be with `mypage = .OpenURL(.URL, icString)`; when I run `len(mypage)`, it returns a value of approximately 100,000, when it should be returning a value of about a million. Can someone explain this?

EDIT: Gimp, I tried your solution, and for some reason, the ReturnStr is still empty. I tried 1024 instead of 2048 as well, but that didn't change anything. I've copied and pasted my code so far.

```
Dim myURL
```

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Select
lastColumn = Selection.Row

For columnNumber = 2 To lastColumn
    workbench = Cells(columnNumber, 1).Value
    myURL = "http://beams.us.yazaki.com/Beams/ViewDetails.aspx?topic=document&pkid=" _
    & workbench
    Dim inet1 As Inet
    Dim mypage As String
    Dim ReturnStr As String

```
Set inet1 = New Inet
With inet1
    .Protocol = icHTTP
    .URL = myURL
    mypage = .OpenURL(.URL, icString)
    ReturnStr = .GetChunk(1024, icString)
End With

Do While Len(ReturnStr) <> 0
    DoEvents
    mypage = mypage & ReturnStr
    ReturnStr = inet1.GetChunk(1024, icString)
Loop

CAMnum = InStr(mypage, "Component Accessory Matrix")
intStart = InStrRev(mypage, "pkid=", CAMnum) + 5
newnum = Mid(mypage, intStart, 6)
Cells(columnNumber, 2).Value = newnum

Next columnNumber
```

Am I missing something here? I searched online for the GetChunk function, and I don't think I'm doing anything wrong syntactically, but maybe it's some fundamental error. Help is appreciated.

Comment: @MarkHall .OpenURL does have a limitation, not the string.

Reference: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=54096

Posted answer below.

Comment: Does this mean you don't need help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11416301/190829) any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using iNet, you need to read the file in chunks when using iNet's OpenURL with the GetChunk function.

Try something like this:

```
 myString = iNet1.OpenURL(.url, icString)
 ReturnStr = iNet1.GetChunk(2048, icString)

 Do While Len(ReturnStr) <> 0
    DoEvents
    myString = myString & ReturnStr
    ReturnStr = iNet1.GetChunk(2048, icString)
 Loop
```

This will read the chunks into ReturnStr and then append them to the end of myString.

After this Do loop your myString will have the entire page in it.