# VBA Inet1 GetChunk function

Tags: vba, excel

EDIT

I'm trying to call inet1.GetChunk to render the entire HTML of a document under one variable name. However, I'm having problems. I've posted my code below:

```
Sub File_Names()

Dim myURL

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Select
lastColumn = Selection.Row

For columnNumber = 2 To lastColumn
    workbench = Cells(columnNumber, 1).Value
    myURL = "my_web_page"&workbench
    Dim inet1 As Inet


Set inet1 = New Inet
With inet1
    .Protocol = icHTTP
    .URL = myURL
    .Execute , "Get"
End With

While inet1.StillExecuting
    DoEvents
Wend

mypage = inet1.GetChunk(1024, icString)


Do While Len(ReturnStr) <> 0
    DoEvents
    mypage = mypage & ReturnStr
    Cells(2, 10).Value = mypage
    ReturnStr = myURL.GetChunk(1024, icString)
Loop


CAMnum = InStr(mypage, "Component Accessory Matrix")
intStart = InStrRev(mypage, "pkid=", CAMnum) + 5
newnum = Mid(mypage, intStart, 6)
Cells(columnNumber, 2).Value = newnum

Next columnNumber


End Sub
```

The problem I get is `mypage = inet1.GetChunk(1024,icString)`. It says "Run Time Error 24:  Object Required". I'm not sure why I'm getting this error message. Any suggestions?

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11437911/190829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.OpenURL` is synchronous; it will open the URL then block until its been fully loaded into the `mypage` variable, so the content is already "under one variable name".

You need to use the `.Execute` method & `_StateChanged` event if you want an asynchronous read. ([Using the State Event with the GetChunk Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733648%28v=vs.60%29.aspx))

Comment: Alex, can you check the edits? I'm still running into problems.